# export not working for *NIX mail script

Tags: ubuntu, email, mutt

For the life of me I can't get mutt on a bash line to use an environment variable OR an alternate muttrc file. The whole process of emailing and receiving the email is working back to front -- just this REPLYTO functionality doesn't seem to be working for me with mutt 1.5.20

i.e.:

```
REPLYTO=somename@place.com mutt -s "test" dest@otherplace.com < /dev/null

env REPLYTO=somename@place.com mutt -s "test" dest@otherplace.com < /dev/null
```

do not work, nor does:

```
printf "my_hdr Reply-to: User Name <somename@place.com>" > muttfile
mutt -s "test" -F muttfile dest@otherplace.com < /dev/null
rm muttfile
```

Maybe my `my_hdr` syntax is wrong or something (does not throw a parsing error though)...

This is all on a Ubuntu 10.04 server box

Comment: Your first example works for me. (mutt 1.5.20)

Comment: Your commands look like they should work. Can you check whether the mail is being sent with the header but something then strips it? (Check with Fcc, and in your local mail queue if you can access it.) Try sending to a different address (start with a local account), and try adding a different (`X-`) header.

Comment: I have the same problem with Mutt 1.4.2.2i